# Android - "reuse" TCP Client?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I want my android client to connect on startup, and then use the same TCP connection to send and receive data every few seconds. How do I do this?
I tried declaring a global socket and using an AsyncTask to send data every second. I checked my server and the client only sent a single message.

Comment: Well, in that case, you have a bug in your server, client or protocol.

Comment: I'm 100% sure its my client because third party TCP Clients work fine (i.e. Hercules)

Comment: How are you making sure that AsyncTask sends data every second? Normally, AsyncTask is executed only once and returns after whatever it is supposed to (doInBackground method).

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm using a handler for that.

Comment: I basically want to open a connection once, but send and receive data every few seconds.

Comment: Have you added debug messages to make sure Handler is starting the AsyncTask after the first time? Are you using the postDelayed?

Comment: If I just have this:  
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                     true);
                             out.println("True");
out.flush()

Then it will send every second.
If I add: 

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                Log.d("test",in.readLine());
It'll only send once.